# Ubercart: Change the product display form label "SKU"

Tags: 6, hooks, ubercart

How would you change the display of SKU? (Which hook manages the product-node display?)

I need sku to output to display "Model #". on a product node page

Drupal Version 6.2x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.

Answer (score 0):

[Showing SKU and changing its label](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/7119/showing_sku_and_doing_sku_adjustments)
Recommend to use "kulvik" user comment.